# Additional basic user can't create new project in visual studio online

Tags: azure-devops

**Context**

I'm using `visual studio online` not the desktop version.

The user with which the main account was created is also basic.

I added another user with basic level.

**Question**

The original user can create new account, while the new basic one doesn't have the option to create the new account.

Really confused! Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio Team Services (formerly VSO) you can add users in the Users tab https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_user but they don't have permissions yet on your project/account.  If you want them to be able to create a Team Project then they will need to be added to the Administrators group.

Navigate to the Administration page by clicking the gear icon at the top right or go to (change the subdomain to your own) https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_admin/_security

Add your new user to the Project Collection Administrators or Team Foundation Administrators so they have the correct permissions - Create New Projects: Allow

You can add other non-admin users to teams or to the project Contributors group for the project.

Comment: can't access this path

Comment: I'm using free version